# Laravel application URL with directory and route group

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

The laravel application url will be something like `app.laravel.com\{clientName}`. All the routes will be following the `client_name`, for example `app.laravel.com\{clientName}\home`, `app.laravel.com\{clientName}\profile`. Will load/ render the application depends on the `clientName`.

In `routes/web.php` I declare two routes

```
Route::get('/{clientName}', 'ClientController@index');
Route::get('/{clientName}/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

And the `ClientController` will look for the `clientName` in the database and load all the client properties and will share it. If the client name doesn't exists it will `abort(404)`.

The issue is `HomeController` currently doesn't do this check, so whatever `clientName` I use everything go through & show the home page.

My question is how can I group all my routes to follow after `clientName` and all the routes will go through the `clientName` validation?

I thought about `middleware`, If I'm using a common `middleware` how can I access the `clientName` in the route, in the middleware?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Laravel official documentation,
You may also use the prefix parameter to specify common parameters for your grouped routes:

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'accounts/{account_id}'], function () {
    Route::get('detail', function ($account_id)    {
        // Matches The accounts/{account_id}/detail URL
    });
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for update, the `prefix` helps me to group, but whatever `clientName` (not in db) the `/home` routes shows the view. How can I do the validation which is in `ClientController` validating `clientName` ? Is there anyway I make all the routes in this `prefix` group to first go through the `ClientController`

Comment: Then you have to use custom middleware. You can also achieve that using a constructor that do the validation. Follow any one.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out `Route::group(['prefix' => '/{clientName}', 'middleware' => 'appclient'], function () {
 Route::get('/', 'ClientController@index');
 
 Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
});` This is the how I'm currently doing it. The issue is how do I get the `clientName` in the URL in my middleware? Its not in the request

Comment: Found it, I can get from `$request->path()`